# passing parameters to controller from iterable component

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

How can I pass parameters to my controller from an iterable component?  I'm using actionSupport with an input checkbox to call an action method in my controller.  I need to pass two values back to the controller that I can reference in my inner class and set the values on two of my properties in the inner class.

Here is the relevant section of my VF page:

```
    <apex:pageBlock id="participantBlock">          
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" id="topBtnParticipant">
            <apex:commandButton id="btnParticipant" value="Add Participant" action="{!addParticipant}" reRender="participantTable" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Participants" columns="1" id="participantSection">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="participantTable" value="{!participantLinesForPage}" var="part">
                <apex:column style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;" width="4%">
                    <apex:commandLink rerender="participantTable" action="{!deleteParticipant}">
                        <apex:param name="del" value="{!part.iterate}"/>
                        <apex:image id="deleteImage" value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icons, 'delete.png')}" width="16" height="16"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact" width="30%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.contactId}" id="targetContactId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.contactName}" id="targetContactName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openContactLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetContactName}', '{!$Component.targetContactId}', 'userLookupIcon{!part.iterate}', 'accountLookupIcon{!part.iterate}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" id="contactLookupIcon{!part.iterate}" /></a>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Add Task" width="6%" headerClass="columnAlignment" styleClass="columnAlignment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!part.selected}" disabled="{!IF(part.selected == true, true, false)}" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!addTaskFromParticipant}" oncomplete="this.disabled=true;" rerender="taskTable" />
                        <apex:param value="{!part.contactId}" assignTo="{!whoid}" />
                        <apex:param value="{!part.contactName}" assignTo="{!whoname}" />
                    </apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="User" width="30%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.userId}" id="targetUserId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.userName}" id="targetUserName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openUserLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetUserName}', '{!$Component.targetUserId}', 'contactLookupIcon{!part.iterate}', 'accountLookupIcon{!part.iterate}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" id="userLookupIcon{!part.iterate}" /></a>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account" width="30%">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!part.accountId}" id="targetAccountId" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!part.accountName}" id="targetAccountName" onFocus="this.blur()" disabled="false" style="width:175px;" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="openAccountLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetAccountName}', '{!$Component.targetAccountId}', 'contactLookupIcon{!part.iterate}', 'userLookupIcon{!part.iterate}'); return false" ><img onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" src="/s.gif" id="accountLookupIcon{!part.iterate}" /></a>                  
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

I was trying to use the `<apex:param>` component and the `assignTo` attribute.  But, that never fires.

When the user selects the checkbox, I want to pass the contactId and contactName for that particular record in the `<apex:pageBlockTable>` and set it equal to the properties `whoid` and `whoname`

I can then reference those properties in my inner class and set the values equal to a couple of properties that I have defined in my inner class that is used elsewhere in my VF page.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!addTaskFromParticipant}" oncomplete="this.disabled=true;" rerender="taskTable" />
                        <apex:param value="{!part.contactId}" assignTo="{!whoid}" />
                        <apex:param value="{!part.contactName}" assignTo="{!whoname}" />
```

To

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!addTaskFromParticipant}" oncomplete="this.disabled=true;" rerender="taskTable" >
                            <apex:param value="{!part.contactId}" assignTo="{!whoid}" />
                            <apex:param value="{!part.contactName}" assignTo="{!whoname}" />
 </apex:actionSupport>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post.  I gave that a try, but the `whoid` and `whaname` properties are still null when I run the code.  My action method is getting entered and excutes, but the properties are null.  The values are not getting passed back to the controller?  I've tried with ActionFunction, but that definitely doesn't work because it is not supported in a iterable component.  Any other ideas?

Comment: <apex:inputCheckbox onchange="addTaskFromParticipant('{!part.contactId}','{!part.contactName}')" /> And apex:actionFunction  out side of apex:pageBlockTable 
<apex:actionFunction name="addTaskFromParticipant" action="{!addTaskFromParticipant}" oncomplete="this.disabled=true;" rerender="taskTable" >
                            <apex:param value="{!part.contactId}" assignTo="{!whoid}" />
                            <apex:param value="{!part.contactName}" assignTo="{!whoname}" />
 </apex:actionFunction >

Comment: I get unknown property `part` because the `apex:params` reference the var in the `pageBlockTable` and those params are now outside of the `pageBlockTable`.

Comment: Change TO <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!whoid}" /> <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!whoname}" />

Comment: I'm getting a javascript error because the arguments passed into the `addTaskFromParticipant` function is the id of the component and not the value?  The error is: `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters: addTaskFromParticipant=function(j_id0:theForm:participantBlock:participantSectio...`